# Google API to detect location closest to the user from a list of locations

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, google-places-api

I have a phone app developed in Ionic which supposedly only supports a few stores. What I want to do is to use Cordova Geolocation to fetch the user's current location, and use it to find a store in our support list closest to their location. What would be the best Google API to use for this, Google Maps or Google Places? Also what would be the easiest way for me to achieve this?

Other than finding the store I don't need to use any other map functionality.

Comment: which type of `store` are you looking nearby user's current location ? you can look into supported types at (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place Search Requests (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests)

A Nearby Search query

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?parameters`

Required parameters in above query

- key :  Your applications API key.
- location : The latitude/longitude around which to retrieve place information.
- radius : Defines the distance (in meters) within which to return place results
- rankby : distance
- type : Restricts the results to places matching the specified type.  list of supported types (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types)

*Example*

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=1500&type=store&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

**IONIC IMPLIMENTATION**

Install the Cordova and Ionic Native plugins

```
`$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation --variable GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="To locate you"`

`$ npm install --save @ionic-native/geolocation`
```

*HTML*

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Google Maps NearBy Search
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div #map id="map"></div>
</ion-content>
```

*js*

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { googlemaps } from 'googlemaps';

declare var google;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
  map: any;
  latLng: any;
  options: any;
  infowindow: any;

  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone, private geolocation: Geolocation) {}
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public geolocation: Geolocation) {}
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.initMap();
  }
  initMap() {
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
      this.latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.longitude);
      this.options = {
        center: this.latLng,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, this.options);
      let service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map);
      service.nearbySearch({
        location: this.latLng,
        radius: 1000,
        type: ['store']
      }, (results, status) => {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            this.createMarker(results[i]);
          }
        }
      });

    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error getting location', error);
    });

  }
  createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: placeLoc
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(place.name);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
  }

}
```